# Angular 2, what does it mean when it navigates to "/component?"

Tags: angular

I am trying to `RouteParam` to a child component let's say with path `/component`. When that component loads, it gets to the end of `ngOnInit()` and I can see for a moment the page load with the proper data binded to it before it redirects the page to `/component?`, which is not recognized in my `RouteConfig`. This takes me back to the index page. I tried to recreate this error with Chrome's console open, but after it redirects me, the log doesn't show only errors, only `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/component?`

All the router stuff appears to work, as it goes to the correct page and loads it correctly for a brief moment. The child component doesn't have a router, so I couldn't have routed to a non-existing page. This component is slightly different from the others as it is the only one that doesn't have a `[routerLink]` in the main nav but I don't think that matters. Everything compiles with npm.

edit: how my routing works (this setup works for every other time I route to other components except this one)

In `app.component.ts`

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/bidding", name:"BidPage", component:biddingC}
])
```

In the parent component in the button click event when it navigates

```
openBidding(a_quotationContractO: quotationContractO){
    this.router.navigate(["BidPage", {product: a_quotationContractO.listing_id}]);
}
```

In the child component's `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit(){
    let listing_id = +this.routeParams.get("product");
    window.alert(listing_id); //this shows the right thing
    //somewhere after here it does the ? redirect automatically
}
```

Does anyone why this is happening?

Comment: I think your problem is not well defined yet. `/component` and `component?` are the same route so if the former is defined, the latter shouldn't confuse `RouteConfig`.  You can test this by going straight to `/component?` and outputting something to the console within the `ngOnInit()` of `/component`. The output will occur indicating that the correct component loaded.  Something else is going on.

Comment: I don't know how to change the path manually. Every time I try to put something like `localhost:3000/component` which I know exists, it treats it like it's invalid and always brings me to `/component/index`. But, about the second one, in the `ngOnInit()`, I displayed the `RouteParam` I passed in, and it was correct.

Comment: Provide details like your router config, how you are navigating with routerLink or navigate

Comment: Added, sorry for not providing it earlier.

Comment: Check whether the app is actually navigating away.  In the problematic component, `import {CanDeactivate} from '@angular/router-deprecated';` Then add `routerCanDeactivate()` function, and `alert('navigating away!')` from within it.  This function is called automatically when the router tries to leave the component.  Is the alert triggered when you navigate to this component?  If not, then the router isn't navigating away as you think; something else is happening